# ERROR running force:org:list: Parse error in file unknown on line 1

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, salesforcedx-cli, vs-code, scratch-org

when I am trying to get org list using command sfdx force:org:list
It is showing me an error: ERROR running force:org:list:  Parse error in file unknown on line 1

earlier it was working fine I am facing this issue after I pulled source using sfdx force:source:pull from my scratch org

even I deleted my project and created one dummy new project to check if this error still continues and it's still there.

I HAVE EVERYTHING UPDATED.

[image: Following image shows what's the actual error]

Answer (score 2):

I had the excact same issue. I believe the root cause was a corrupted json file in either `C:\Users\myuser\.sf` or `C:\Users\myuser\.sfdx`. I was lazy so I just deleted both folders to solve the issue. Please note that this will log you out of all authorized orgs.